# Can you set Gitlab CI stage so other stages don't wait for it to finish?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Let's say I have these stages defined in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
    - build
    - analysis
    - tests
    - deploy
    - post-deploy
```

Since `analysis` takes a lot of time and I don't really care about the result (I also have `allow_failure: true` set) - is it possible to somehow define to start `analysis` and then immediately launch the next stage `tests`?

I didn't find any reference to similar topic on [official docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#jobs).

EDIT:

The main idea is that all other stages can be run as if the `analysis` didn't even exist. If i put `analysis` to same stage as `tests`, then both `analysis` and `tests` will run at the same time, however `deploy` won't be launched until both of them finish. This is no good. I want `tests` to finish and then launch `deploy`, after `deploy` finishes I want to launch `post-deploy`. I really don't care about `analysis` result, **I simply want to trigger it and continue with the deployment.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stages are per definition serial. One stage will be executed after another.

If you want to process analysis and tests parallelly, you have to define them on the same stage.

```
stages: 
 - build
 - processing
 - deploy
 - ...

analysis:
 stage: processing
 ...


tests:
 stage: processing
 ...
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#stage

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question. I know about this option, however in this scenario if tests finished the rest of stages (deploy, post-deploy) will still be waiting on analysis to finish. Is it possible to start analysis and continue with the rest as if the analysis wasn't in the stages?

Comment: I have edited my question, so it's (hopefully) more clear

Comment: I see. There is no such feature. As the concept of the stages is strictly linear. As you don't need the result of the analysis, I would simply add it at the end.

Answer (score 17):

Since v12.8, you can use `needs: []` to start jobs start immediately. Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs

Comment: To be clear: the jobs will run immediately **only** if explicitly setting `needs: []`, right? otherwise they are strictly serial as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47287038/3165014) suggests?

Answer (score 3):

There's a workaround available in newer GitLab versions: [Trigger a child-pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#trigger-syntax-for-child-pipeline) for the jobs you don't want to wait for. By default a child-pipeline will return "success" as soon after it got started, you need to explicitly [set the strategy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#linking-pipelines-with-triggerstrategy) if you'd like to wait for the jobs in the child-pipeline. So *by accident* this is exactly the behaviour you'd like to have.

The UI is not the best right now, but I'm positive it'll improve in future versions of GitLab. It's a workaround after all, but it should do the job.

Comment: 2 years after the initial accepted answer, this is now the correct answer.